What CPU speed constraint is required for stockfish to lose to a human?
I've seen that it's now basically impossible to beat stockfish as a human, but with what amount of processing power? Is that only a given with unlimited super computing? Or can this be accomplished with something like a smart phone app level of cpu power and still beat any human 99.99% of the time?

a supercomputer with depth 1 would still lose. I think it is the depth that matters

@cmgchess thanks, my question though is if the depth is unlimited, what processing power constraint would render stockfish at below average human skill? i dont want to restrict the logic in any way, only the maximum flops/cpu "power"

Stockfish is easily capable of beating top humans on phone hardware, and probably could do so even if running very asymmetric time control (e.g. 1 second per game for the computer vs 5 minutes per game for the human).
On fast computers, Lc0 is a roughly even match to grandmasters (but not top grandmasters) with a knight handicap.

phone hardware is very fast. thats not really helping me get an idea of how to answer the question.

my guess is that any computer that is capable of compiling a modem version of SF is superhuman
